# How to get back to the same game after quitting races

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've just started playing GTA 5 Online with a few friends, and am having trouble getting all of us into the same game after completing a few races.

Normally, we setup the online game via Invite Only. We do this so if we have friends that the others don't, we can just invite them in.

After doing a few races, we get back to the voting screen and choose the option to Quit. When we do that, it throws us each in different game sessions. So we all have to get back into the same together again by doing invites. How can we just get back into the same game after doing missions, races, etc... without having to rejoin?

Comment: I'm inclined to say _you can't_ but I don't know for sure. There are [some](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/1nzd28/how_do_i_stop_getting_separated_from_my_friends/) [posts](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200697346-Staying-in-the-same-session-after-a-mission-and-heist-missions) on other forums which support my inclination, but [this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/733724-grand-theft-auto-online/67599128) seems to offer a way it might work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you and your friends in the voting screen all click on 'freemode' you all should I get in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly but my guess is when everyone is on the voting screen, make everyone click the free mode option and it should place all players in the same lobby.

Comment: Can you back your answer up with some evidence? That way, the OP and anyone else can be sure that this method will work.